# vuejs 3: inject key into child component?

Tags: vuejs3

Versions:

```
VueJS: 3.x
Chrome: Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (x86_64)
macOS: Big Sur 11.5.2
```

My use-case must be common, and I am mildly surprised that it does not work "out of the box".

I have these simple routes:

```
/patients/new
/patients/1
/about
```

which I access from a single-page application (SPA) through vueJS `router-link`s:

```
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/patients/new">New Patient</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/patients/1">Update Patient</router-link>
```

`/patients/1` returns a pre-populated HTML FORM with details of patient with ID `1`.
`/patients/new` returns the same HTML FORM with blank entries.

Intuitively, if I visit `/patients/1` link, and then visit `/patients/new`, I would expect HTML FORM to be empty; conversely, if I visit `/patients/new` and then `/patients/1`, I would expect the HTML FORM to be pre-populated accordingly.

This is not what happens.  Instead, the SPA does not re-create / re-mount the HTML FORM.

Solution:  many articles suggest using a reactive variable referenced by a `:key` attribute in the HTML FORM.  Then whichever link we visit, as long as we change the reactive variable, the vueJS component that houses the HTML FORM should be re-created / re-mounted.

My approach:  `provide` a reactive variable at the root component, and `inject` it within the vueJS component (ie, the `Patient` component here) that renders the HTML FORM.

Here's what my root component looks like:

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import Vue from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: "App",
  provide() {
    return {
      routePath: Vue.computed(() => this.$route.path)
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

where the reactive variable is `routePath`.  Then in the `Patient` component, I have this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Patient",
  inject: ['routePath'],
  ...
});
```

with the HTML FORM defined with the `:key` attribute like this:

```
<template>
  <form :key="routePath">
    ...
  </form>
</template>
```

I believe the basic idea here is sound, but it is not working, and it does seem like a cumbersome approach.

So, here are my questions:

1. Is this approach sound?
2. Why is the `Vue.computed()` invocation broken?  Here's the stack trace from Chrome console:

```
App.vue?3acc:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'computed')
    at Proxy.provide (App.vue?3acc:9)
    at qe (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2463)
    at Pr (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6713)
    at Lr (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6632)
    at Tr (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6562)
    at D (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4421)
    at N (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:4396)
    at m (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3991)
    at K (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5140)
    at mount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3477)
```

Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I've resolved the error with `Vue.computed()` by simply using: `import { computed, defineComponent } from 'vue'`.  I'm suspicious that provide / inject do not work in my scenario because Patient is not a sub-component of App.  The more general problem remains: how to toggle between links and coerce the Patient component to re-create / re-mount.

Comment: This issue is summarized elsewhere here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/974

Answer (score 0):

It appears this issue is unresolved in vueJS 3.x.  See [open issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/974) for details.  There are work-arounds.  Eg, see [this github project](https://github.com/adamsol/vue-pocket-router).  In my case, I've decided to change the workflow to avoid said issue.