# vueJS 3.x: navigate from page after HTML form-submit

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

Versions:

```
vueJS: 3.0.0
vuex: 4.0.2
Chrome: Version 94.0.4606.61 (Official Build) (x86_64)
```

One advantage of SPA frameworks like vueJS is that they offer some efficiencies in network consumption (ie, fewer server hits by delivering UI/UX assets to client in bulk, and hopefully minimizing server requests).  But I'm running into a scenario where just the opposite happens:  ie, I am required to revisit the server in order to navigate between vueJS components/views.  This seems highly contradictory to the SPA ethos, and I'm suspicious something simple must be wrong in my setup.  Details follow.

`router/index.js`:

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
import Car from '@/views/Car.vue'
import Bike from '@/views/Bike.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '@/views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/cars/new',
    name: 'New Car',
    component: Car
  },
  {
    path: '/cars/:id',
    name: 'Edit Car',
    component: Car,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/bikes/new',
    name: 'New Bike',
    component: Bike
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

Then in `Car.vue` component, I have a form-submit handler something like this:

```js
    handleSubmit(event) {
      let form = event.target;
      if (form.checkValidity()) {
        // Add or update Car.
        window.location.href = window.location.origin + process.env['BASE_URL'];
      }
      this.wasValidated = true
```

Rather than using `window.location.href`, I tried to use:

```js
this.$router.push('Home');
```

But that had no effect.  That is, the URL in the browser address bar began as something like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/`, and remained that way after the router-push.

I also tried pushing to other routes, like `About`; in that case, the browser address bar properly toggled to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/about`, but the page content remained the same!

Clearly, this cannot be the right behavior.

Can you suggest how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`this.$router.push('Home')` tries to push `'Home'` as a *path*, but there's no matching path in your router config, nor is there a fallback route (for `404`s), so the route simply doesn't change.

If you meant to push the route by *name*, the [`$router.push()` argument](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort) needs to be an object:

```js
this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
```

If you prefer to use a path, the path of `Home` is actually `/`:

```js
this.$router.push('/')
```

Comment: Good point. But I think the more general issue is the one cited here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370178/vuejs-3-inject-key-into-child-component ... the point being is that the component I want to navigate to is already on the page, so in that case, vueJS does not refresh the DOM.

Comment: I just posted a new issue caused, I believe, by the same router-behavior:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69469819/vuejs-3-x-for-tabbed-navigation-how-can-i-reference-component-but-not-load-it