# vueJS 3.x: for tabbed navigation, how can I reference component but not load it?

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5

Versions:

```
VueJS: 3.x
Bootstrap: 5.x
Chrome: Version 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (x86_64)
macOS: Big Sur 11.5.2
```

The issue I outline here is very similar to [one I raised a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370178/vuejs-3-inject-key-into-child-component); see my answer there for a short explanation.

I am using tabbed navigation through Bootstrap 5.x styling; one `div` looks this way:

```
    <div class="tab-content mt-5" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <Home/>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="new-car" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="new-car-tab">
        <Car/>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="scan-barcode" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="scan-barcode-tab">
        <ScanBarcode/>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="about-tab">
        <About/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

That is, I have tabs like this:

```
Home | New Car | Scan Barcode | About
```

The key point here is that *all* vueJS components are rendered to the main page as part of tabbed navigation.  The end-result is that I cannot use the router (ie, `this.$router.push({name: 'Home'}` is effectively a no-op) to navigate between tabs; that is, the vueJS router correctly thinks all components are already on the page and will not instigate any kind of page refresh.  Moreover, the barcode reader, which uses my WebCam, immediately turns on streaming video -- even though I may not be on the `Scan Barcode` tab!

QUESTION:  how can I set up tabbed navigation (still using Bootstrap 5.x styling) such that vueJS component are lazy-loaded in some way?  IE, I *do not* want a component to load / mount unless I am actually on that tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See docs on [dynamic components in vueJS](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#dynamic-components-with-keep-alive).

I resolved this issue by using `<component>` in a way that resembles an HTML radiobutton:  that is, only one tab (and by implication, only one component) is ever active at one point in time.

Changes to the code listed in the question that work for me are:

```
    <div class="tab-content mt-5" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
        <component :is="getActiveComponentOrNull($options.components.Home.name)"></component>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="new-car" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="new-car-tab">
        <component :is="getActiveComponentOrNull($options.components.Car.name)"></component>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="scan-barcode" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="scan-barcode-tab">
        <component :is="getActiveComponentOrNull($options.components.ScanBarcode.name)"></component>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="about" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="about-tab">
        <component :is="getActiveComponentOrNull($options.components.About.name)"></component>
      </div>
    </div>
```

where `$options.components` are supplied in the enclosing component / view definition:

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    About, Home, Car, ScanBarcode
  },
  ...
};
```

and `getActiveComponentOrNull` is a method defined on the enclosing component like so:

```
  methods: {
    getActiveComponentOrNull(name) {
      if (this.currentComponent == null || this.currentComponent.name != name) {
        return null;
      }
      return this.currentComponent.name
    }
  }
```

In the bootstrap 5 tabs that I employ, which are HTML `button`s, you need to set up a `@click` handler like this:

```
<button @click="currentComponent=$options.components.Home" class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
```

This solution works for me, although it has its drawbacks.  For example, for each tab-click, the method `getActiveComponentOrNull` is called for each tab (four times in my case).  Maybe there is a clever way to get the same behavior with a computed / reactive variable.

Also, it's important in this solution that your tabbed components gracefully unmount (Eg, if you are using streaming video for `ScanBarcode`, you want to be sure that when that component unmounts, that the resources it uses -- video in this case -- are gracefully shut off).